# How to apply a gradient to a UIImageView using a UIImage as a mask

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIImage` inside a `UIImageView`. I want to overlay a gradient from right to left in the shape of the `UIImage`.

I can render the `UIImage` as a template and apply a tint to the `UIImageView`, but obviously that only has one colour rather than a gradient. I saw some stuff on here about using the `UIImage` as a mask but I couldn't figure it out. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There might be easier ways but if I got you right this could work for you:

```
// create image and image view
let image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

// create the gradient
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.colors = [
    UIColor.red.cgColor,
    UIColor.green.cgColor
]
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
gradient.frame = imageView.bounds

// add a mask to the gradient
let mask = CALayer()
mask.contents = image?.cgImage
mask.frame = gradient.bounds

gradient.mask = mask

// add the gradient as a sublayer to the image view's layer
imageView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

**Result:**

[image: result]

Comment: That works, but layer masks use the alpha channel of the image to set the mask, not the brightness of the pixels. As long as that's what you want...

Comment: It's a little more work to create an alpha channel from a brightness map, but doable.

Comment: @DuncanC Can you maybe provide a sample or something? :)

Comment: A sample of what? Mapping a brightness map to an alpha channel?

Comment: @DuncanC Yeah, that's what I meant. Or maybe some source to recommend regarding that topic...

Comment: Did you use the image as an Original Image?